# ANDROID | Cambio de comportamiento al crear apk firmada SDK 33 Android 13

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout

Llevo unas cuantas horas enfrentándome a un problema al usar la apk[RELEASE] ya firmada con Android Studio - Mi versión actual del IDE es: Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 1

**GradleVersion 8.0
Gradle plugin version 8.1.1**

Cuando compilo la apk para google Play hay librerías que dejan de funcionar

Usando el modo StrictMode en el log observo que hay algunas librerias que NonSdkApiUsedViolation :

StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V
at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:419)
at android.os.StrictMode$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.accept(Unknown Source:2)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.getPublicMethodRecursive(Class.java:2944)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2931)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2449)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.ViewUtils.makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows(ViewUtils.java:93)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1056)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:889)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:763)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:203)
at com.saria.sariamateria.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:102)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8591)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8570)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1384)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4150)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4325)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2574)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8762)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:604)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)

También:

StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z
at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:419)
at android.os.StrictMode$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.accept(Unknown Source:2)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2932)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2914)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.ViewUtils.(ViewUtils.java:53)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelper.java:251)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:121)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:108)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:876)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1028)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:983)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1145)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1106)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1148)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1106)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1148)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1106)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:692)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:544)
at com.saria.sariamateria.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:72)
at com.saria.sariamateria.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:66)
at com.saria.sariamateria.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:101)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8591)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8570)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1384)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4150)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4325)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2574)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8762)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:604)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)

No veo claro en la documentación que hay que cambiar.

Todas las librerias estan actualizadas a ultima versión, incluso he subido a sdk 34 pero no observo ningún cambio

Todo los componentes son androidx.

Entiendo el problema pero no entiendo absolutamente que hay que hacer exactamente.

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar...